# Web Components with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, web-component

I am starting with Web Components with Vuejs and have a basic question. Do we need to include the Vue js library in the host application for the Web Components to work or is it independent?

Answer (score 3):

If you create a Native Web Component without any framework or dependencies then you can use them in Vue, React, Angular or just raw JavaScript.

If you create a Vue based Web Component then you need VUE to be able to run it anywhere. If your company switches to React then you will need to run Vue and React or convert your components to Native or to React.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies, yes I was referring to VUE based Web Components only.